# How do i fix the unbound local error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Error
selfpoints += cardPoints
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'selfpoints' referenced before assignment

```
class userpoint_status:
     def __init__():
         selfpoints = 0
     def increase_points():
         self.points += cardPoints
         print("You have",selfpoints,"points")
         if selfpoints > 21:
                 lose_game()
```

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple occurences in your code where you type `selfpoints` instead of `self.points`. You need to put the dot there so it becomes an instance variable. Given that `cardPoints` and `lose_game` are global variables you won't have any more errors.